# Select Top and Last rows in a table (SQL server)

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm using this statement in SQLServer and it works fine:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 *      
FROM [SomeTable]
```

It gives me the `TOP 1000` records from `SomeTable`, now which keyword should I use instead of `Top` if I need the `Bottom 1000` records from the table?

Comment: `TOP 1000` without `ORDER BY` means "first random 1000 rows".

Answer (score 89, accepted):

To get the bottom 1000 you will want to order it by a column in descending order, and still take the top 1000.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 *
FROM [SomeTable]
ORDER BY MySortColumn DESC
```

If you care for it to be in the same order as before you can use a common table expression for that:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT TOP 1000 *
    FROM [SomeTable]
    ORDER BY MySortColumn DESC
)

SELECT * 
FROM CTE
ORDER BY MySortColumn
```

Comment: Thanks @Khan. Just as clarification - if I have a db table with 1100 records with ID's of 1 through 1100, does `SELECT TOP 1000` mean I will get records w/ ID of 101 thru 1100? IE `TOP` in this case refers to the latest created records?

Comment: Ah - In response to my last comment above, according to my tests, the behavior is the opposite of what I wrote. `Top` returns the records 1 - 1000....hmmm..good to know, bc if I ever have a table with more than 1000 records, or even more than 200 records, if I `Edit top 200 rows`, I could get my some of my pseudo primary keys wrong (roleID, userID, etc) if I manually increment them. I'd want to create a `201` record, but roleID of `201` would already exist and I'd be attempting to enter a duplicate. Never before thought of this issue..

Answer (score 7):

You must sort your data according your needs (es. in reverse order) and use select top query